# Error: unexpected '}'

Tags: r, syntax-error, warnings

I'm trying to generate a random data. Basically, I copied this code from the book, however it doesn't work for me. It works until it reaches the line stated in the warning:

```
Error: unexpected '}' in:
"+ this.seg[,j] <- rnorm(segSize[i], mean=segMeans[i,j], sd=segSDs[i,j])
+ }"
```

The code looks as following:

```
for (i in seq_along(segNames)) {
  + cat(i, segNames[i], "\n")
  +
    + # empty matrix to hold this particular segment’s data
    + this.seg <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow=segSize[i], ncol=length(segVars)))
    +
      + # within segment, iterate over variables and draw appropriate random data
      + for (j in seq_along(segVars)) { # and iterate over each variable
        + if (segVarType[j] == "norm") { # draw random normals
          + this.seg[,j] <- rnorm(segSize[i], mean=segMeans[i,j], sd=segSDs[i,j])
          + } else if (segVarType[j] == "pois") { # draw counts
            + this.seg[, j] <- rpois(segSize[i], lambda=segMeans[i, j])
            + } else if (segVarType[j] == "binom") { # draw binomials
              + this.seg[, j] <- rbinom(segSize[i], size=1, prob=segMeans[i, j])
              + } else {
                + stop("Bad segment data type: ", segVarType[j])
                + }
        + }
    + # add this segment to the total dataset
      + seg.df <- rbind(seg.df, this.seg)
      + }
```

Can somebody explain why it stucks on that line and what has to be changed? Thanks!

Comment: I assume you didn't copy/paste the code with the "+" signs ?...

Comment: Remove the + sign in front of each line there...Then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to copy the code without the "+" signs ... then the code works!